# unable to get value from select tag to $_POST array

Tags: php, html, arrays

i have this in my from, i am getting values from other input tags and check boxes but not getting value from select tag in $_POST array 
here is the code

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="fcity"  value="<?php echo $res['f_city'];?>" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" title="Choose one of the following...">
<option data-tokens="Lahore" <?php echo ($res['f_city']=='Lahore')?'selected':'' ?>>Lahore</option>
<option data-tokens="Islamabad" <?php echo ($res['f_city']=='Islamabad')?'selected':'' ?>>Islamabad</option>
<option data-tokens="Karachi" <?php echo ($res['f_city']=='Karachi')?'selected':'' ?>>Karachi</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Show how you access `$_POST` in back end and include `<form>` tag in question

Comment: <form data-toggle="validator" method="post"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> //select tag </form>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      print_r($_POST);
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the 'value' attribute on each 'option' tag instead of in the 'select' tag

e.g.:

```
<option value="Lahore" data-tokens="Lahore" <?php echo ($res['f_city']=='Lahore')?'selected':'' ?>>Lahore</option>
```

Comment: When excluding `value` attribute form submit will take `<option>` text as it's value instead.

Comment: I Think when we use data-tokens="Lahore" then we don't use value

Comment: @user5403480 `data-tokens` has nothing to do with form submit (unless using js to parse it and pass to server)